# Copying list in python: deep vs shallow copy: gotcha for me in python?

Tags: python

So this is what I tried to do.

```
vectorized = [0] * length
for i,key in enumerate(foo_dict.keys()):
    vector = vectorized
    vector[i] = 1
    print vector
    vector = vectorized
print vectorized
```

So what I was hoping was for example the length is 4. So i create
a 4 dimension vector:

```
  vectorized=[0,0,0,0]
```

now, depending on the index of dictionary (which is also of length 4 in this case)
create a vector with value 1 while rest has zero

```
so vector = [1, 0,0,0]  , [0,1,0,0] and so on..
```

Now instead what is happening is:

```
 vector = [1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0] .. and finally [1,1,1,1]
```

even vectorized is now

```
   [1,1,1,1]
```

Whats wrong I am doing. and how do i achieve what i want to achieve.
Basically I am trying to create unit vectors.
Thanks

Comment: I wish more question were this quality. +1. I would only recommend improving the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line (these lines, really):

```
vector = vectorized
```

copies the list reference. You need to do a shallow copy of the sequence contents.

```
vector = vectorized[:]
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a single list and then giving it several different names. Remember that a = b doesn't create a new object. It just means that a and b are both names for the same thing.

Try this instead:

```
for ...:
    vector = [0] * length
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
vector = vectorized
```

is not making a copy of `vectorized`. Any time you change `vector` from then on, you are also changing `vectorized.

You can change the first line to:

```
vector = vectorized[:]
```

or

```
import copy
vector = copy.copy(vectorized)
```

If you want to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

While in Python, when you assign a list to a new list, the new list is just a pointer rather than a brand new one.

So when you trying to modify the value of "vector", you are actually changing the value of "vectorized".
And in your case, 
`vector[i] = 1`
is same as
 `vectorized[i] = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you write `vector = vectorized` it is not creating a copy of the array, rather it is creating a binding between the two.

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object.

http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html

This should help you get it sorted out.

And here's a little snippet from the python REPL to show you what I mean.

```
>>> vectorized = [0] * 4  
>>> print vectorized  
[0, 0, 0, 0]  
>>> vector = vectorized  
>>> vector[1] = 1  
>>> print vectorized  
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

EDIT: Jeez you guys are fast!